# Referencing drawable using custom attributes

Tags: android

I'm trying to pass references to images in my custom view. I figured it would be alot cleaner to define the drawable in a layout than to have a list of some sort. However, I keep getting a NullPointerException. Below is my current code:

**Custom View:**

```
TypedArray array = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Button, 0, 0);
try {
    float scale = array.getFloat(R.styleable.Button_scale, 1.0f);
    keys.put(ButtonState.DOWN, MainActivity.ScaleBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), array.getResourceId(R.styleable.Button_down, 0)), scale));
    keys.put(ButtonState.UP, MainActivity.ScaleBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), array.getResourceId(R.styleable.Button_up, 0)), scale));
} finally {
    array.recycle();
}
```

**Attributes:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <attr name="scale" format="float"/>

    <declare-styleable name="Button">
        <attr name="scale"/>
        <attr name="up" format="reference"/>
        <attr name="down" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

**Layout:**

```
    <com.lark.app.Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        custom:down="@drawable/button_down"
        custom:up="@drawable/button_up"
        custom:scale="0.5"/>
```

I've verified that the images are indeed in the drawable folder.

EDIT: Logcat: http://pastebin.com/J3AZ8M5a

Comment: NPE?  where do you get it?

Comment: can you share your logcat also?

Comment: I got the exception when trying to get the reference to "Button_down". It should be the line directly underneath "scale" in the custom view.

Comment: @Metehan I've edited the main post to include logcat information.

Comment: The error is in your MainActivity's OnCreate method: `at com.lark.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)` what do you have on line 41 and around there

Comment: @Metehan I'm adding the custom view to a FrameLayout, though I doubt this is the issue. I have several other custom views that work with no problem, though I'm referencing the drawables directly rather than a custom attribute.

Comment: If you can paste what you have on your OnCreate method until the 45th line maybe we can be more helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60672/discussion-between-omlet-and-metehan).